# Is there a way to link with image in Vue?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I have a problem to link to other url when I click image by using Vue.

It suppose to be able to link by clicking images but it does not work.

If there are anyone who can help me I am very appreciated.

My code looks like below.

HTML

```
<section class="bg-light page-section" id="portfolio">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center"><br>
          <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase works-text">Works</h2>
          <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Selected work that has been created with the help of many.</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item" v-for="(obj, key) in portfolioJSON" :key="key"  >
          <a class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" target = "_blank" v-bind:href="`${obj.url}`">
            <div class="portfolio-hover">
              <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                <!-- <! <i class="fas fa-plus fa-3x"></i> -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <img :src="`${obj.img}`" class="img-fluid" >
          </a>
          <div class="portfolio-caption works-text">
            <h4 class="works-text">{{ obj.caption }}</h4>
            <p class="text-muted works-text">{{ obj.title }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

```
export default {
    data() {
      return{
        portfolioJSON: [
           {
                img: require('../assets/img/sukimatch/sukimatch.png'),
                caption: 'Sukimatch',
                title: 'WEBSITE, BANNER DESIGN',
                url: "https://sukimatch-f887f.firebaseapp.com/"
            },
            {
                img: require('../assets/img/portfolio/greencosjapan.png'),
                caption: 'Greencosjapan',
                title: 'WEBSITE',
                url: "https://greencosjapan.com"
            }
        ]
    }
    }, computed: {
    imageArray: function() {
        return this.portfolioJSON.map(obj => obj.img)
    },
    urlArray: function() {
        return this.portfolioJSON.map(obj => obj.url)
    }
},

}
```

Comment: I hope you know hyperlinking is done with `<a>` tag, so did you try wrapping `img` inside `a` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code won't work like that, you should call `${obj.img}` ,this is the new ES6 syntax for template literals

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 sk-item" v-for="(obj, key) in portfolioJSON" :key="key">
          <img :src="`${obj.img}`" class="img-fluid" alt="" >
        </div>
```

You can read more about it here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

It's very useful , you should use it in all places in your code, where you can do it.

```
img: require('../assets/img/sukimatch/sukimatch.png'),
                caption: 'Sukimatch',
                title: 'WEBSITE, BANNER DESIGN',
                url: "https://sukimatch-f887f.firebaseapp.com/"

:title="`${obj.title}`"
:href="`${obj.url}`"
:img="`${obj.img}`"
```

Hope this could helps you :)

Update:

```
    export default {
      data() {
            return {
               portfolioJSON: [
               {
                    img: require('../assets/img/sukimatch/sukimatch.png'),
                    caption: 'Sukimatch',
                    title: 'WEBSITE, BANNER DESIGN',
                    url: "https://sukimatch-f887f.firebaseapp.com/"
                },
                {
                    img: require('../assets/img/portfolio/greencosjapan.png'),
                    caption: 'Greencosjapan',
                    title: 'WEBSITE',
                    url: "https://greencosjapan.com"
                }
            ]
}, computed: {
        imageArray: function() {
            return this.portfolioJSON.map(obj => obj.img)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Marin thank you for your reply. Your info was also helpful. However it still does not work. I updated code above as you said I closed img tag inside of a tag. And also added `:href="`${obj.url}`"`though. Do you see any wrong part?

Comment: Hmm in this code, which you provide, you missed this open and closing `` :href="`\`${obj.url}\``"

Comment: hmm I have closed like as you provided.  :href="`${obj.url}`" . I kinda lost now.. but tks anyway!

Comment: Its just I put  :href="`${obj.url}`" and closing apostrof are disappeared here..

Comment: Can you show me your full code in vue component, again ? You should use escapes like : \\

Comment: I updated my code above. I really appreciated that you are taking your time for me. @Marin

Comment: When you use computede property to return soemthing , then you should call it in your html code and loop over it :

And your data shoult return something like : `data() { return {  } } `

In your code, the data , doesn't return anything ...

Comment: @rewe check my answer again , I updated your script , check it

Comment: Okej, so I will try to return obj.url in computed as same as obj.image. :) Thanks!

Comment: If you just loop straight over portfolioJSON , I think you will get all info in the Array , if you want to filter something , then maybe in your computed function , you should write some additional logic , which has to return only img and url .

Comment: I updated my code above. But I just need to get all info in the array at once, so I maybe delete computed. I appreciated your help a lot :) @Marin

Comment: Actually it used to work to link url but it suddenly stopped so im cofusing..

Comment: Yes , in your case, I don't see a reason to use computed property at this stage

You're welcome :)

Comment: A minor detail: perhaps use alt instead of title?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an href on your image. Everything else looks like it would work. I just tried an example in a codepen that works fine. Post a code pen with a more complete example. It might be a CSS problem.

Your code:
`<img :src="obj.img" class="img-fluid" href="obj.url">`

should be

`<img :src="obj.img" class="img-fluid"`

Comment: hi @Jess thank you for your reply. I just updated my code above, I am still not sure what wrong with my code. I continue to try to solve it.

Comment: Delete everything except for the `a` tag and the `img` tag. It should work fine.

Comment: Sorry I updated a wrong code, but should I delete all code except a and img tag?

Comment: Yeah, you can keep the for loop, but all of the other divs and stuff, get rid of them. Make a minimum example of an `a` tag that wraps an `img` and then slowly re-add all the other stuff you've deleted. That way you can tell what's breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me. When your asset folder is inside the public folder.

```
<div style="backgroundImage: url('~../../assets/images/image_1.jpg')">
```

Otherwise if its inside the src use the alias "@"

```
<div style="backgroundImage: url('~@/assets/images/image_1.jpg')">
```